# Output value and whether it exists in SQL Server 2008 Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, boolean

I am trying to create a query that outputs (1) The value (2) Whether the value exists or not. I tried

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
    SELECT [IP_ADDR1_TEXT]
    FROM [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER]
    WHERE [IP_ADDR1_TEXT] = '10.10.10.10'
) , [IP_ADDR1_TEXT] 
THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END
```

And I get error. Thanks.

CLARIFICATION

When I try

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
    SELECT [IP_ADDR1_TEXT]
    FROM [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER]
    WHERE [IP_ADDR1_TEXT] = '10.10.10.10'
) 
THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END
```

It only outputs 1 or 0. I would like it to output the IP address, and 1 or 0, depending on whether it exists or not.

```
IP Address   EXISTS
10.10.10.10    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the work

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN COUNT(distinct [IP_ADDR1_TEXT]) > 0 THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END AS Some_blah
    FROM [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER]
    WHERE [IP_ADDR1_TEXT] = '10.10.10.10'
```

What you have already tried, will work as well. Just mention the column before `CASE` statement like below

```
SELECT [IP_ADDR1_TEXT],
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (
    SELECT [IP_ADDR1_TEXT]
    FROM [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER]
    WHERE [IP_ADDR1_TEXT] = '10.10.10.10'
) 
THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END
FROM [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER]
WHERE [IP_ADDR1_TEXT] = '10.10.10.10'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do this.

```
SELECT cast(count([IP_ADDR1_TEXT]) as bit) as IP_Exists
FROM [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER]
WHERE [IP_ADDR1_TEXT] = '10.10.10.10'
```